# JavaScript app sometimes unable to find Backbone / Marionette

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, module, marionette

We've a couple of webshops online at the moment. All of them running on Backbone.Marionette. We've install Rollbar for client side error reporting.

For most visitors, everything works really well. However, every now and then we get the following errors (not all of them at the same time):

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Backbone`

`Uncaught TypeError: Backbone.Marionette.Application is not a function`

`Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`

`Can't find variable: jQuery`

Anyone experiencing the same issues? We're not using requireJS at the moment.

Comment: Ive experience your problems before, it is usually due to the order in which you are loading your js files, or there is an error which you can probably see in the console, that makes the execution stop. How are u loading your js files?

Comment: Do you load your scripts as a single bundle or separately? If separately, where do your `<script>` tags sit in the HTML? Do you use the `async` attribute in any of your `<script>` tags?

Comment: We've loaded each script seperately (to improve debugging), without using the async attribute. We're loading our scripts just before closing the <body> tag. An example website is lindenhoff.nl

Comment: I would put it down to temporary server issues, since in the case of success the scripts will always be loaded in the right order. You could _hugely_ improve load time by concatenating and minifying your scripts.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with server issues, since we're loading all JS files locally. We're using Rails with Sprockets to load all JS files in a certain order... Since we're getting these weird errors in production, we switched back to unminified assets. Sprockets doesn't support source-maps at the moment, so this seemed like the only solution to track errors in produciton to us. :/

Comment: @Vernon Did you ever find out what it was? We've been getting something similar in Rollbar logs with a Vue application recently.